# How to hide port number in web.py?

Tags: port, web.py

In web.py we need to host the our application py using $ python xyz.py 8080 command, also by default it takes 8080 itself. While accessing from the browser one has to put the port number in the url like this, **www.xyz.com:8080**. How can I remove the port number and give the url like www.xyz.com to host my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

web.py default server is intended only for development. In production you should set up a dedicated web server, like Apache or lighttpd, and run it (the server) on port 80, so your question is not related to Python as @Álvaro pointed out. There are three documented ways to deploy web.py over Apache: [CGI deployment](http://webpy.org/cookbook/cgi-apache), mod_wsgi deployment ([Red Hat example](http://webpy.org/cookbook/mod_wsgi-apache), [Ubuntu example](http://webpy.org/cookbook/mod_wsgi-apache-ubuntu)) and [FastCGI](http://webpy.org/cookbook/fastcgi-apache).

Answer (score 0):

For a regular, unencrypted HTTP connection, your browser by default uses port 80, so

```
http://www.xyz.com
```

is the same as

```
http://www.xyz.com:80
```

But to use port numbers below 1024 you need administrator permissions.

Comment: I want to use different port number. How can I get the permission? Also my apache is running in 8080, that's why I want a different port where I can run another web.py server but without port number.

Comment: What kind of system are we talking about? Linux? Windows? OS X? Is it your machine or someone else's?

Comment: @user1532043 - Is your question actually related to Python? I have the impression that you're simply asking how to change the Apache port, except that you aren't really asking that :-? You obviously cannot load a site on port 8080 using a URL that points to port 80, unless the second site acts as proxy and loads the first one—that's how HTTP works.

Comment: Yeah it's related to pyhon. I am using Linux system.

Comment: Then try "sudo python xyz.py 80"

Comment: Dude, it's running properly, but I don't want :80 or :8080 or any other port number in the url. How to do that?

Comment: As I said in my answer above, if it binds to port 80, you don't need to specify it in the url

Comment: If I don't do that then it'll simply take to my apache's www folder.

Comment: Then apache is running on port 80 (not 8080 like you said above), and you can't run another program on the same port unless you stop apache